# Does MathWorks Simulink prohibit multiple inheritance for system objects?

Tags: matlab, simulink, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

**The Problem:**
I am trying to use some System Objects inside a 'User-defined Function' block in Simulink.
When I try to run the block, I get an error saying the following -

```
Diamond-shape inheritance is not supported in code generation. Class 'X' inherits from base class 'Y' via two or more paths.
```

**Background:** Class X inherits from classes A, B, C - all of which inherit from class Y. There is no conflict between any property/method/class definition between any of these classes. All of them implement their own unique methods, and there is no overloading of a common method/property.

Class X works in MATLAB - I have been able to successfully work with instances of class X.

What I'm **not** sure of is whether Simulink supports multiple inheritance / diamond shape inheritance, when it is guaranteed that there are no conflicts.

So I would be very interested in finding out if I can make use of class X in Simulink without having to refactor other classes to remove the multiple inheritance.

I have looked at the following MATLAB Central answer, and blog post trying to understand whether multiple inheritance poses any issues.

1. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93189-how-does-matlab-solve-the-diamond-problem-in-multiple-inheritance
2. https://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/06/08/diamond-of-death/

But I couldn't find anything related to Simulink or Simulink Codegen

Comment: The error message says "Diamond-shape inheritance is not supported in code generation." and you are asking us whether diamond-shape inheritance is supported? No, it's not. That is what the error message tells you. Very clearly and plainly.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Simulink seems to throw an error at something that MATLAB doesn't have a problem with. This quirk should be documented somewhere, wouldn't you say? I tried to find out about it, but didn't get anywhere. Which made me further skeptical of the error message itself. 
Also, one comes across obscure workarounds in MATLAB all the time - I was hoping someone would be able to point me to one

Comment: @CrisLuengo if you prefer the title were a bit different, then that would make a lot of sense

Comment: "Diamond-shape inheritance is not supported **in code generation**." In MATLAB it is fine, but when you try to generate C++ code from the MATLAB code, you cannot have diamond inheritance (probably because it is illegal in C++). I don't know much about Simulink, but it looks like it uses code generation for the user-generated blocks?

Comment: Oh, I see. I just learned that Simulink can do "interpreted execution" and "code generation". The former uses MATLAB to run the MATLAB code, the latter uses code generation, and supports only the subset of the MATLAB language that can be translated to C++. Try to run your code using "interpreted execution".